# SQL Server 2008 - Join causing slow performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, query-optimization

I asked the below query earlier, but it was downvoted as the query plan was not provided which I was not aware of. This time around I have provided the query plan and hope some suggestions/comments on how to improve the following query:

The following query takes 5 min to return about 68000 records. But If I remove, the LKP_PrivateSource (i.e. The last Left Join) from the query, then it takes 1 SECOND to return 68000 records. BTY, there are no records in LKP_PrivateSource table. Any idea about what's causing the issue?

```
Select 
    Case IsNull(LNK.StockID,0)
        When 0 Then AE.StockID
        Else LNK.StockID
    End StockID,
    IsNull(AE.LinkID,0) LinkID,
    IsNull(LNK.CapitalID,0) CapitalID,
    DE.SourceName,
    AE.SourceDate 'Date',
    IsNull(AE.Formula,'') Formula
From 
    AE_RevenuData AE
Left Join 
    Linking LNK With(NoLock) ON LNK.LinkID = AE.LinkID
Inner Join 
    DE_DataEntities DE ON DE.EntityID = AE.EntityID
Inner Join 
    DataEntityIDs TE ON TE.EntityID = DE.EntityID
Inner Join 
    STG_LockedEntityData STG ON STG.StockID = IsNull(LNK.StockID, AE.StockID) AND STG.CapitalID = IsNull(LNK.CapitalID, 0) 
Left Join 
    LKP_PrivateSource PS ON PS.PSourceId = AE.PSourceID
Where 
    AE.ProjectID IN (13)
    AND AE.LinkID IS NOT NULL
```

Please see below the plan:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1017]=CASE WHEN [Expr1026]=(0) THEN [MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[StockID] as [AE].[StockID] ELSE [MYDBNAME].[dbo].[INV_InvestorFundLinking].[StockID] as [LNK].[StockID] END))
   |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1027]))
        |--Filter(WHERE:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData].[StockID] as [STG].[StockID]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[INV_InvestorFundLinking].[StockID] as [LNK].[StockID],[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[StockID] as [AE].[StockID]) AND [MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData].[CapitalID] as [STG].[CapitalID]=[Expr1019]))
        |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1019]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[INV_InvestorFundLinking].[CapitalID] as [LNK].[CapitalID],(0)), [Expr1026]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[INV_InvestorFundLinking].[StockID] as [LNK].[StockID],(0))))
        |         |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([AE].[LinkID]))
        |              |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData].[LinkID] as [STG].[LinkID]))
        |              |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Expr1027] ASC))
        |              |    |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([TE].[EntityID])=([AE].[EntityID]))
        |              |    |         |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Uniq1008], [DE].[ListingID]))
        |              |    |         |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([TE].[EntityID]))
        |              |    |         |    |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DataEntityIDs] AS [TE]))
        |              |    |         |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DE_DataEntities].[PK_DE_DataSources] AS [DE]), SEEK:([DE].[EntityID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DataEntityIDs].[EntityID] as [TE].[EntityID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |              |    |         |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DE_DataEntities].[IX_DE_DataSources] AS [DE]), SEEK:([DE].[ListingID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DE_DataEntities].[ListingID] as [DE].[ListingID] AND [Uniq1008]=[Uniq1008]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
        |              |    |         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1018]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID], [Expr1020]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[Formula] as [AE].[Formula],''), [Expr1021]=CONVERT(bit,[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[IsSumOfFunds] as [AE].[IsSumOfFunds],0), [Expr1022]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[ClientSpecificSource] as [AE].[ClientSpecificSource],N''), [Expr1023]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[GenericSource] as [AE].[GenericSource],N''), [Expr1027]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[PSourceID] as [AE].[PSourceID],(0))))
        |              |    |              |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[IX_AE_RevenueData] AS [AE]), SEEK:([AE].[ProjectID]=(13)),  WHERE:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID] IS NOT NULL) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |              |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData] AS [STG]))
        |              |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[INV_InvestorFundLinking].[PK_Linking_1] AS [LNK]), SEEK:([LNK].[LinkID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[LKP_PrivateSource].[PK_LKP_FactsetSource] AS [PS]), SEEK:([PS].[PSourceID]=[Expr1027]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Please see below the plan without Join on LKP_PrivateSource

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1015]=CASE WHEN [Expr1024]=(0) THEN [MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[StockID] as [AE].[StockID] ELSE [MYDBNAME].[dbo].[Linking].[StockID] as [LNK].[StockID] END))
   |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1027]))
       |--Filter(WHERE:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData].[StockID] as [STG].[StockID]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[Linking].[StockID] as [LNK].[StockID],[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[StockID] as [AE].[StockID]) AND [MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData].[CapitalID] as [STG].[CapitalID]=[Expr1017]))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1017]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[Linking].[CapitalID] as [LNK].[CapitalID],(0)), [Expr1024]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[Linking].[StockID] as [LNK].[StockID],(0))))
                 |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([AE].[LinkID]))
                      |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([AE].[LinkID])=([STG].[LinkID]))
                      |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([TE].[EntityID])=([AE].[EntityID]))
                      |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Uniq1008], [DE].[ListingID]))
                      |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([TE].[EntityID]))
                      |    |    |    |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DataEntityIDs] AS [TE]))
                      |    |    |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DE_DataEntities].[PK_DE_DataSources] AS [DE]), SEEK:([DE].[EntityID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DataEntityIDs].[EntityID] as [TE].[EntityID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                      |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DE_DataEntities].[IX_DE_DataSources] AS [DE]), SEEK:([DE].[ListingID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[DE_DataEntities].[ListingID] as [DE].[ListingID] AND [Uniq1008]=[Uniq1008]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
                      |    |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1016]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID], [Expr1018]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[Formula] as [AE].[Formula],''), [Expr1019]=CONVERT(bit,[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[IsSumOfFunds] as [AE].[IsSumOfFunds],0), [Expr1020]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[ClientSpecificSource] as [AE].[ClientSpecificSource],N''), [Expr1021]=isnull([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[GenericSource] as [AE].[GenericSource],N'')))
                      |    |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[IX_AE_RevenueData] AS [AE]), SEEK:([AE].[ProjectID]=(13)),  WHERE:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID] IS NOT NULL) ORDERED FORWARD)
                      |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[STG_LockedEntityData] AS [STG]))
                      |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MYDBNAME].[dbo].[Linking].[PK_Linking_1] AS [LNK]), SEEK:([LNK].[LinkID]=[MYDBNAME].[dbo].[AE_RevenueData].[LinkID] as [AE].[LinkID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: do the query plan without the join and see what happens.

Comment: You should also post the execution plan when you remove tha last `LEFT JOIN`. Also, this would probably be a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: A few things you should check for if you haven't done so already: (a) out-of-date statistics, (b) statistics sample size too small, (c) index fragmentation.

Comment: Table scans on `dbo.STG_LockedEntityData` and `dbo.DataEntityIDs` not looking good.

Comment: Are **all** the foreign key columns indexed? This is valid for **all** tables

Comment: Please post the plan without `LKP_PrivateSource`

Comment: @marc_s: Which table you are referring?

Comment: Stuff like this: `Inner Join STG_LockedEntityData STG ON STG.StockID = IsNull(LNK.StockID, AE.StockID) ` is a performance killer ... try to avoid calling functions on your indexed columns in WHERE and JOIN clauses!

Comment: @marc_s: not necessarily. With a `HASH MATCH` (which is what happening without that `LEFT JOIN`) it's OK

Comment: @marc_s: Ohk.. I'll change that and take care of it... BTY, that's not the reason of this problem as It stands even after removing IsNull

Comment: @Quassnoi: I was looking more at the awfully slow `nested loop` joins - probably because some of the FK columns aren't indexed ....

Comment: @Quassnoi: You are right, STG_LockedEntityData is a staging table and there is no index on that. Moreover when I removed this table from the query, added the lKP_PrivateSource table
 and ran, it works fine. But, still i could not figure out the exact problem.

Comment: @marc_s: they should not be there at all, the outer tables are not filtered. `HASH MATCH` would be preferred here.

Comment: Can someone confirm, if No indexing on STG_LockedEntityData table could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, adding a `LEFT JOIN` to `LKP_PrivateSource` makes optimizer use `NESTED LOOPS` instead of a `HASH JOIN` to join `STG_LockedEntityData` (which goes earlier).

It's hard to tell why it is, but to improve the nested loops, create an index on `STG_LockedEntityData (stock_id, capital_id)`